# Introduce custom property in OData

Tags: odata

In my database User table I have DataTime field called DateDeleted - which is null while user exists and is set to the proper value when user "is deleted".

I wonder if there is a way to introduce IsDeleted property for User entity so that

http://odata/service.svc/Users(1)/IsDeleted

will return true or false depending on whether DateDeleted is set or not

My research in google hasn't got any results and I am almost sure it is not possible to implement through odata. Am I right?

Comment: With code-first this is possible: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3870575/861716

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the built in providers this is not possible on the WCF DS side of things. You might be able to somehow do this on the EF side (expose it as a property of the EF entity), but I'm not sure if that's possible.
On the WCF DS side, you would have to implement a custom provider in order to do this. Which may be quite a lot of work unfortunately. If you're interested see this for starters: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2010/01/07/data-service-providers-getting-started.aspx.
What Shawn refers to above is a method on the custom provider interface.

Comment: Hi Vitek, thanks for looking into this issue. I do already have a custom data provider in place. The problem I have is that in case when I introduce new property to entity class, it gives me Error 3004, requiring to regenerate db to add this property as a filed in the table. I must be missing the basic step. If I have entity class generated from edmx model - how do I add _'IsDeleted'_ property to it?

Comment: Also, just to mention, this property will have to be exposed through odata.

Comment: Are you sure you have a custom provider? Do you actually implement IDataServiceMetadataProvider and IDataServiceQueryProvider interfaces? If you do then it should be relatively easy to modify them to expose an additional computed property. If you don't and you just define a DataService<T> where T is an ObjectContext, then you're using the built-in EF provider, in which case this is not possible to do on the WCF DS side of things.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the value you want by implementing the method DataServiceQueryProvider.GetPropertyValue.

Please find the reference here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.providers.idataservicequeryprovider.getpropertyvalue.aspx

The method takes two parameters, the entity object (a User instance) and the resource property (in this case "IsDeleted"). You can try to get the property value of "DataDeleted" from the entity object, and return the value of "IsDeleted" as you want.

Comment: Dear Shawn, thanks for getting back. My model is designed in edmx (not code first) - is there a way to use this approach with edmx model? I just don't seem to figure out where and how to implement the above. Thank you for your help