# Add property to WCF EF OData service

Tags: entity-framework, wcf-data-services, odata

I have created an Entity Framework model which I expose through WCF Data Services. I want to add a property to one of the entities that is not in the database, so I created a partial class for that entity with a public property. However this property does not get exposed over the service - what do I need to do to make this happen?

I tried adding the [DataMemberAttribute()] to the property, but no help. What am I missing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a computed property in Data Services (OData)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3863113/how-to-create-a-computed-property-in-data-services-odata) or [Introduce custom property in OData](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6461836/introduce-custom-property-in-odata)

Comment: Yes, you are right. So basically it is not possible without lots of work. At this point it's easier for me to change the underlying database to add my required fields via a view, Thanks