# Is there any workaround for WCF Data Services to bypass absence in OData V3 enum support?

Tags: c#, wcf, enums, wcf-data-services

I'm trying to use Entity Framework 5.0 (Model-First approach) with WCF Data Services 5.6.2 and ran into following trouble:

When Entity Data Model for WCF Data Service contains Enum property when Data Service will fail at initialization stage:

> The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is: "The property 'X' on type 'Y' is of type 'enum-type-here' which is not a supported primitive type."
>
> The exception stack trace is:
>
> System.Data.Services.Providers.ObjectContextServiceProvider.PopulateMemberMetadata(ResourceTypeCacheItem
>   resourceTypeCacheItem, IProviderMetadata workspace,
>   ProviderMetadataCacheItem metadataCacheItem, PrimitiveResourceTypeMap
>   primitiveResourceTypeMap) at System.Data.Services.Providers.ObjectContextServiceProvider.PopulateMetadata(ProviderMetadataCacheItem
>   metadataCacheItem) at
>   System.Data.Services.Providers.BaseServiceProvider.LoadMetadata(Boolean
>   skipServiceOperations) at
>   System.Data.Services.DataService`1.CreateInternalProvider(Object
>   dataSourceInstance) at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.CreateMetadataAndQueryProviders(IDataServiceMetadataProvider&
>   metadataProviderInstance, IDataServiceQueryProvider&
>   queryProviderInstance, Object& dataSourceInstance, Boolean&
>   isInternallyCreatedProvider) at
>   System.Data.Services.DataService`1.CreateProvider() at
>   System.Data.Services.DataService`1.HandleRequest() at
>   System.Data.Services.DataService`1.ProcessRequestForMessage(Stream
>   messageBody) at SyncInvokeProcessRequestForMessage(Object , Object[] ,
>   Object[] ) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object
>   instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean
>   isOperationContextSet)

The [only advise](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/odatateam/archive/2012/08/29/odata-101-using-the-notmapped-attribute-to-exclude-enum-properties.aspx) I've found to fix the issue is marking such properties as [NotMapped], but when I annotate T4 generated classes' enum properties with this attribute it does nothing and Data Service still fails.

Also EF provider for WCF DS [doesn't support System.Data.Services.IgnorePropertiesAttribute](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ffeee9e2-b96c-4b16-8ab6-d48de066f5b7/ignore-properties-attribute-not-working-in-wcf-data-services-50-rtm-release) that could be used to hide enums only with Reflection provider.

How can I expose strings instead of DB stored int-backed enum values using WCF Data Services?

Comment: I would be happy with just the int value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The facts that "[EF provider for WCF DS doesn't support System.Data.Services.IgnorePropertiesAttribute](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ffeee9e2-b96c-4b16-8ab6-d48de066f5b7/ignore-properties-attribute-not-working-in-wcf-data-services-50-rtm-release)" and "[EF provider also doesn't allow to expose any 'new' properties that aren't in the underlying  EDM model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3863113/how-to-create-a-computed-property-in-data-services-odata)" gives me a sad answer:

No, we can't expose Enums and even custom string representation for them using WCF Data Services with EF Provider.

Comment: I think this problem is exist yet after 2 years, how do you think about , I hate this exception...